# How to keyframe a crop in Premiere Pro CC

Tags: premiere, timecode

I am working on a school project, and it starts off with a 5 second count up that takes up the full screen. I am using the prebuilt *insert timecode* effect built into Premiere. What I have done is cropped all but the minutes and seconds out of the view.

What I would like to do next is to transition it to the bottom right corner while shrinking it.

Any help/advice would be welcome. If theres another program that does it easier, then feel free to let me know.

**EDIT:**

Here is what I have:
[image: Cropped Big Version]

Here is it without the crop:
[image: Non-Cropped Big Version]

Here is what I would like to have the timer transition to:
[image: Cropped Small Version]

Here is the non-cropped version of the smaller timestamp:
[image: Non-Cropped Small Version]

Comment: Welcome Jordan :) I would like to help you, but your question is not clear. Please add a screenshot and try to describe what do you want to achieve. For a simple crop just keyframe the [scale value](http://i.stack.imgur.com/L78ny.png) of your footage. Note: If you have to scale the footage about 107%, might be better to set the project to a smaller output format like 720p.

Comment: @poor I have added some pictures, I hope this illustrates further what i'm trying to do. I have a feeling that this is going to be rather simple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I start I'd like to mention that this would be much easier in After Effects. If you plan on doing this more often, you should consider learning AE to be able to do things like that faster.

So, to follow your approach I created a transparent layer, put the timecode effect on it and cropped it using the crop effect. It looks like this right now:

[image: stage 1]

Since you want to resize and move it, you'll need to activate the animation for two parameters in the effects panel: The "size" parameter of the timecode effect and the "position" parameter under the motion effect (which is applied to each clip by default). You can do this by clicking the clock symbol next to the parameters name (see the next image). Make sure that your playhead (in the timeline) is at position 00:00, since activating the animation will create a keyframe at the current position.

[image: stage2]

Now, move the playhead to the point where you want the animation to end (i.e. the timecode has arrived at your desired position and size). First, alter the percentage value of the "size" parameter of the Timecode effect. A keyframe will automatically be created (see the small diamond shape in the timeline next to the effect settings panel). Then, adjust the "position" parameter of the motion effect. Again, a keyframe will automatically created. Adjust both parameters until you're happy with size and position. Then you're basically done.

[image: stage 3]